# How would one implement a custom symbol table in C++ using a tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, symbol-table

My teacher says to identify the actual symbol being used and then to use a tree to determine the codewords. I don't understand this so I'm coming here because there are smart and articulate people on here!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sounds like Huffman coding? https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/poop/huff/info/  But context is unclear and SO isn't very good with applied telepathy and clairvoiance

Comment: Assuming your symbol table is `[symbol, value]`, you could use `std::map`, which uses a tree.  Or if you are gutsy and have time, write your own tree that has nodes of `[symbol, value]`, and sort by the symbol.  Hint:  you are *mapping* or *associating* a symbol with a value.